# Remove an element from JsonResult in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I've a `JsonResult` object to return from a MVC method, but I need to remove one element from it before send it.

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to do it without mapping it because the object is huge and very complex.

How can I achieve this?

For eg.:

```
public class MyClass {

   public string PropertyToExpose {get; set;}
   public string PropertyToNOTExpose {get; set;}
   public string Otherthings {get; set;}

}
```

and

```
JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
result = Json(myObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and then **REMOVE** PropertyToNOTExpose from the result.

**UPDATE from real code:**

```
public JsonResult GetTransaction(string id)
{    
    //FILL UP transaction Object

    JsonResult resultado = new JsonResult();

    if (CONDITION USER HAS NOT ROLE) {
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(transaction);
        jObject.Remove("ValidatorTransactionId");
        jObject.Remove("Validator");
        jObject.Remove("WebSvcMethod");
        resultado = Json(jObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } else {
        //etc.
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new object, excluding the properties you don't want sent in the result...

```
var anonymousObj = new {
   myObject.PropertyToExpose,
   myObject.Otherthings
};
JsonResult result = Json(anonymousObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Another options could be to convert the object to a [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) and remove the property using [JObject.Remove Method (String)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Remove.htm)

```
var jObject = JObject.FromObject(myObject);
jObject.Remove("PropertyToNOTExpose");
var json = jObject.ToString(); // Returns the indented JSON for this token.
var result = Content(json,"application/json");
```

Comment: Yeah, but the object is hughe and I was trying to avoid de map. Thats why I want to remove it.

Comment: Another idea would be to serialize the object to a `JObject` and remove the property before passing it to result.

Comment: Thanks Nikosi, that was I looking for. But it changed the structure, I don't know why. Now the ajax doesn't recognize it :(

Comment: show an example of the new structure using the original myObject example. I'm sure it will be simple to fix

Comment: @LeandroTupone I found the issue and updated my answer. Call `ToString` on the `JObject` to get the Json to send in the result.

Comment: I get the data now from js side, but in an string. and not in a json object. I think the tick is on the conversion to JsonResult... Anyway I accept your answer because is right, but I've to looking for this conversion.... :S

Comment: you can parse string string to json on client side

Comment: yeap! Thanks a lot. Finally I change to ActionResult and then return Content(json,"application/json");

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute on your property.  This will cause the `JavaScriptSerializer` to ignore it.  However, this means that it will be ignored on deserialization as well.  I'm not sure whether that is an issue for your situation or not.

```
public class myClass 
{
   public string PropertyToExpose {get; set;}
   [ScriptIgnore]
   public string PropertyToNOTExpose {get; set;}
   public string Otherthings {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it, so even when not answer me, I think is a good answer to SO.
Actually I have to filter some elements if the user has not the rol, so I've a little conditional logic. If the user has the rol, I show them all, if not, I filter it